# Spark SQL throwing error "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown field type: void"

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am getting below error in Spark(1.6) SQL while creating a table with column value default as NULL. Ex: create table test as select column_a, NULL as column_b from test_temp;

The same thing works in Hive and creates the column with data type "void".

I am using empty string instead of NULL to avoid the exception and new column getting string data type.

Is there any better way to insert null values in hive table using spark sql ?

```
2017-12-26 07:27:59 ERROR StandardImsLogger$:177 - org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown field type: void
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:789)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:746)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply$mcV$sp(ClientWrapper.scala:428)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:426)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:426)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.liftedTree1$1(ClientWrapper.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.retryLocked(ClientWrapper.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.withHiveState(ClientWrapper.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.createTable(ClientWrapper.scala:426)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.CreateTableAsSelect.metastoreRelation$lzycompute$1(CreateTableAsSelect.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.CreateTableAsSelect.metastoreRelation$1(CreateTableAsSelect.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.CreateTableAsSelect.run(CreateTableAsSelect.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withCallback(DataFrame.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:829)
```

Comment: `select cast(NULL as string)` ?

Comment: Thanks @philantrovert. It worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find much information regarding the datatype `void` but it looks like it is somewhat equivalent to the `Any` datatype we have in Scala.

The table [at the end of this page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types) explains that a `void` can be cast to any other data type.

Here are some JIRA issues that are kinda similar to the problem you are facing

- [HIVE-2901](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2901)
- [HIVE-747](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-747)

So, as mentioned in the comment, instead of `NULL` you can cast it to any of the implicit data types.

```
select cast(NULL as string) as column_b
```

Answer (score 0):

I started to get a similar issue. I build the code down to an example

```
WITH DATA
AS (
  SELECT 1 ISSUE_ID,
         DATE(NULL) DueDate,
         MAKE_DATE(2000,01,01) DDate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 ISSUE_ID,
         MAKE_DATE(2000,01,01),
         MAKE_DATE(2000,01,02)
)
SELECT ISNOTNULL(lag(IT.DueDate, 1) OVER (PARTITION by IT.ISSUE_ID ORDER BY IT.DDate ))
       AND ISNULL(IT.DueDate)
FROM DATA IT
```

Comment: Hi Jørgen! Welcome :) As I understand you've created a [minimal, workable example (mwe)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which is awesome! Since it isn't an answer to the original question, I would suggest making this a comment, or better yet, contributing this to the question itself by proposing an edit.